# FLUTTER showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, android-appwidget, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

how can i controll the default pop property of bottom sheet.Like I want to  asign a value to a variable when showModalBottomSheet is popped .I have tried to do with controllers

Comment: Can you show some code of yours

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do :

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                        var a = "desired value";
                        return Widget;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger when the bottom sheet is popped/dismissed with an `AnimationController` like this:

in your `StatefulWidget`'s `State`:

```
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.isDismissed) {
        print("dismissed");
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose;
    super.dispose();
  }
```

in your `showModalBottomSheet`:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => Container(),
          transitionAnimationController: _controller, //  assign the controller
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set    `isDismissible: false,` and than add one button (Close button) on tap of button, you have to do your code and pop the bottomSheet.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
   isScrollControlled: true,
   isDismissible: false,
   shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
       top: Radius.circular(15),
     ),
   ),
   context: context,
   builder: (context) {
   return SizedBox(
          height:
               MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (0.6),
          child: Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
               child: Column(
                      children: [
                       Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                             InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
// Add your code here. which you want to perform before closing bottomSheet
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                 },
                                 child: const Icon(Icons.close)),
                             InkWell(
                                 onTap: () {},
                                 child: const Text(
                                 "Reset",
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15),
                        //Other widgets of bottomSheet
                        Container(
                           height:
                             MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (0.5),
                           color: Colors.amber,
                        )
                   ],
              ),
         ),
     );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help

I solved the problem with WillPopScope

```
popfunction() {
      SelectedValue = tempValue;
      Navigator.pop(context, true);
    }


onWillPop: () async {
        return popfunction() ?? false;
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to click on the `back button` , `showModalBottomSheet` closed ,
I suggest used `useRootNavigator: true` in `showModalBottomSheet`